# Detecting whether iOS App was launched by a Local Notification in Unity

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I'm using the [NotificationServices](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NotificationServices.html) to schedule local notifications for my Unity game on the iOS platform. I'm successfully scheduling and presenting the local notifications, however I haven't find a way to detect whether the user has opened (launched or resumed) my app as a result of **opening the local notification** (not the app directly).

I tried to check for `NotificationServices.localNotificationCount > 0` in `OnApplicationPause(false)` (when the app is entering foreground) but sometimes `NotificationServices.localNotificationCount` is `> 0` even though the user hasn't opened the local notification (maybe `NotificationServices.localNotificationCount` was updated before, when a local notification was received when the app was in foreground, etc.).

I need a safe way to detect that my app was opened by a local notification. Does anyone know how can I achieve that in Unity?

Answer (score 2):

I was having issues finding a reliable way to do this so I just wrote one. It's not the most advanced but you can have it for free.

I have a class called `GLTNotificationResponder` I wrote, just put the two files (`.h` + `.m`) in `Assets/Plugins/iOS` inside your Unity project.

You'll have to add a few lines to `UnityAppController.mm` inside XCode, but only if you do a fresh build ( either new build or a 'REPLACE' ), not for subsequent rebuilds of an app.

And in Unity, create a GameObject and add `NotificationResponder.cs` to it.

I hope it helps!

---

http://pastebin.com/v2DLcZb3 - GLTNotificationResponder.h

http://pastebin.com/tupUvABx - GLTNofiticationResponder.m

http://pastebin.com/CC6qA7Sz - NotificationResponder.cs

http://pastebin.com/PuyDtL5z - UnityAppController.mm changes

---